# Errors appear using Jsoup: Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, element

I'm trying to use a simple `jsoup` program. I'm using eclipse and created a maven project with the `jsoup-1.8.1.jar` in my Maven depedencies.

```
package com.testing.com.testing.maven.eclipse;
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  

public class Main{  
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page").get();  
                String title = doc.title();
                System.out.println("title is: " + title);  
    }  
}
```

But when I run it these errors appears

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
    at com.testing.com.testing.maven.eclipse.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:792)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1122)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1059)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:946)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:501)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:799)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:735)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:673)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2500)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1930)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:260)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    ... 12 more
```

This is what my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.testing.maven.eclipse</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>com.testing.maven.eclipse</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>  
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>  
      <version>1.8.1</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I'm using JDK 16.0.2

I tried checking similar problems in stack overflow but they have different errors. Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: **That shouldn't happen unless** (0) a hardware glitch, which wouldn't recur -- does this? (1) a bug in the server, not lilkely for wikipedia (2) a bug in your Java, not likely if it's standard (3) something in the network is **tampering your data**. Are you in an environment or location subject to monitoring, like a business, organization, or institution? Are you in a country where the government does this, or on an ISP that does? Do you have any antivirus or endpoint-security that 'inspects' or 'protects' your data? ...

Comment: ... Does this occur going to other servers (especially TLS1.3)? Going from other programs: different browsers like Chrome and Firefox, openssl (including nodejs, python, perl, php), Windows (powershell) Invoke-WebRequest? Via other network access like a cellphone or a local (or distant!) hotspot? PS: this _probably_ isn't about programming or development, but I think it's premature to suggest moving.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install manually

mvn install:install-file -Dfile= -DgroupId= 
-DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=